# Nothing in my ArrayList<Uri>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In my onCreate method, I instantiate an ArrayList:

```
    happyList = new ArrayList<>();
```

On the click of a button, the following method is called (it should take/pick two pictures):

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    pictureCounter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pictureCounter++;
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.w("error","IOException");
            }catch (NullPointerException nullEx) {
                Log.w("error","NullPointerException");
            }
            // Camera.
            final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
                final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
                final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                cameraIntents.add(intent);
            }
            // Filesystem.
            final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // Chooser of filesystem options.
            final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
            // Add the camera options.
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the onActivityResult, each picture's Uri should be added to the array at the end:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
                final boolean isCamera;
                if (data == null) {
                    isCamera = true;
                } else {
                    final String action = data.getAction();
                    if (action == null) {
                        isCamera = false;
                    } else {
                        isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }
                Uri selectedImageUri;
                if (isCamera) {
                    selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                } else {
                    selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                }
               // mainView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                happyList.add(pictureCounter, selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want these URIs in this array so that I can later send the first to an ImageView and be able to 'scroll through' the array to show the next picture in the same ImageView.

When I print out my array however (via ArrayList.toString() method), it is blank. Any idea why this is and how to fix?

Comment: why don't you debug it?  Maybe put a log statement before `happyList.add(pictureCounter, selectedImageUri);
            }` ?

Comment: Hey, Can you explain how "outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);" from 'dispatchTakePictureIntent' methos and "selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;" from 'onActivityResult' methos are linked and value is getting passed?

Comment: @DsD outputFileUri is an instance variable of the class

Comment: Are you getting correct value/URI from this try block -> "photoFile = createImageFile();
                outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);"?
Debug and make sure if your createImageFile() returns correct URI..

Comment: @DsD it does. I can send the URI to an ImageView to display and it does.

Comment: I think your happyList has missing item(0) as pictureCount++ is the first line in the for-loop.